# FTP upload never throws an error issue

Tags: c#

I've created an application that uploads files to a remote FTP server. If the credentials (address, username, password, etc.) are wrong I want to to throw an error. As of right now it never does. What is wrong with my code? When the credentials are correct it does successfully upload.

here is the class I am using:

```
 public void upload(string remoteFile, string localFile)
    {
        try
        {
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
            FileStream localFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFile);
            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            try
            {
                while (bytesSent != 0)
                {
                    ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
                    bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            localFileStream.Close();
            ftpStream.Close();
            ftpRequest = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        return;
    }
```

and where I'm calling the upload function in the form:

On button click =

```
    ftp ftpClient = new ftp(@"ftp://weburl.com/", "user", "password");
    UploadToFTP("testing/file.txt" , @"C:\file.txt");

    void UploadToFTP(string FTPfolder, string LocalFolder)
    {
        try
        {
            ftpClient.upload(FTPfolder, LocalFolder);
            Messagebox.Show("Uploaded Successfully!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Messagebox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: you're never going to see a messagebox because you're swallowing your errors in the `upload` function

Comment: Looks like if there is an error, its spitting it to the consol, but isn't waiting for readkey, so the consol is disappearing, you never catch another exception in your call because the catch in the function is handling the error. Inside the function replace `Console.WriteLine` with `Messagebox.Show`

Answer (score 0):

From my comment if there is an error, its spitting it to the console, but isn't waiting for readkey, so the console is disappearing, you never catch another exception in your call because the catch in the function is handling the error. Inside the function replace `Console.WriteLine` with `Messagebox.Show` to see the caught errors

```
 public void upload(string remoteFile, string localFile)
    {
        try
        {
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
            FileStream localFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFile);
            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            try
            {
                while (bytesSent != 0)
                {
                    ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
                    bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Messagebox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
            localFileStream.Close();
            ftpStream.Close();
            ftpRequest = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Messagebox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your `upload` function is eating the exception.

I would rewrite your catch block this way:

```
        try
        {
            // ....
        }
        catch (WebException webEx)
        {
            string message = string.Empty;

            if (webEx.Response.GetType() == typeof(FtpWebResponse))
            {
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)webEx.Response;
                message = string.Format("{0} - {1}", response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription);
            } else
            {
                message = webEx.Message;
            }

            throw new Exception(message);
        }
```